# Convert number to string in scientific format

Tags: r, string, numbers, format

I have some numbers, such as `num = c(0.1, 0.001, 1.12345e-5)`. I want to turn `num` as string, with each element displayed in scientific format, with 3 digits. That is `num_after_convert = c( '1.00e-1', '1.00e-3' , '1.12e-5')`. Any good solution?

Comment: Have a look at [`?formatC`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/formatc.html), `example(formatC)`, and possibly also [`?sprintf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sprintf` function will give you the most control of the output and can guarantee scientific notation:

```
> num <- c(0.1, 0.001, 1.12345e-5)
> sprintf("%4.2e", num)
[1] "1.00e-01" "1.00e-03" "1.12e-05"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your vector always has at least one element already in scientific notation as in your example:

```
format(num,digits=3)
```